# AngularJs ui-router child view disappear

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CrLukiNbYRL8AreLS2rt?p=preview

Pls, click A, and **after B and C appear**, click A again. C will disappear.

I have a routes:

A - abstract, it has 2 named views A-1, A-2 and a main menu.
B - is a sub menu which sits in A-1@A view
C - is a content related to B menu and it sits in A-2@A view

Main menu in route A has ui-sref to B route.

B route controller has logic:

```
if($state.is('B')) {
    $state.go('C', {defaultContentId});
}
```

So when I click main menu element, it opens B with default content. This is ok, no problems. But then, if I click same element in main menu, my default sub menu is selected, and my content is empty. Any breakpoints in B controller not fired.

**WORKAROUND (not answer)**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(!$state.is(toState.name, toParams) && $state.includes(toState.name, toParams)){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.warn('Same state prevented');
    }
});
```

I have only 2 layers of navigation, so I can check if parent clicked and prevent click. Not a solution tho, just a fishy patch ...

So. In my example I have only A root, but in a real example I have... let's assume - A1, A2, A3 e.t.c. So now with this workaround, I can click A1, but if B is loaded and I click A1, it will be prevented. Still I can freely transit to A2 and A3 from A1 -> B layer.

Comment: Strange behavior indeed. I tried poking around by adding console logs for the state on click for the `ui-sref tags` and I see `Id:3` in the initial click to `A` and `id: x` in all clicks related to `B`. but in the case you specified I don't see `Id` as a state parameter. Don't know why this is happening but could be a clue. I will keep looking.

Comment: Well, here is my ticket https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller for A.B is not re-executed because A.B.C is a child state from A.B. Therefore going from A.B.C to A.B does not change the second level in the state tree.

That's the cool thing about ui-router, it keeps states loaded and offers the ability of reloading only certain parts of the ui.

If you want to actually re-execute when you navigate state, you can specify a full reload with `ui-sref-opts` attribute:

```
<menuItem ui-sref="A.B" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" class="btn btn--main">A - Click-me</menuItem>
```

Comment: Well, it's a bit strange behavior, because A is 1 lvl higher than B, why should it keep state that 1 lvl lower.

Comment: I mean - I'm intentionally going to A, I don't need B anymore.

Comment: You're not going to A, the link you're clicking (on template A) has the code to go to B

Comment: Thx for the answer, I'm not at PC right now, need to check it. :)

Comment: So, should we always force reloading on parent links? You was right, I was going to B, but from C.

Comment: I do a little research: reload v0.2.5 Boolean (default false), If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search params. - my state is changing from C to B (event is fired).

Comment: Thats the thing, you are changing your state from A.B.C to A.B, thus B state is not being retriggered. A.B.C is children from A.B. which means, as you said, if search params hasn't changed, nothing has changed from that B state. Thats the expected behaviour. I don't know how to explain better :(

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. I'm just calculating C in router B but maybe this is design error.

Comment: It does make sense when you look at it from outside, but looks strange from this context. Thanks @frankies for providing the info.